# Post content shown with italic style

Tags: html, css, styles, italic

I don't know what to do about this; if you check the post content of [my website](http://demilovatoonline.com/danithemes), It is shown with Italic Style. I don't know how to delete this property. Can somebody help me?

[This is the css code of my posts](http://pastebin.com/q0jHmXbJ)

Comment: which content are you talking about?

Answer (score -1):

Simply add this code at the bottom of your stylesheet:

```
.post .content, .comment .content {
     font-style: normal;
}
```